# mysql memcached

Tags: mysql, sql, memcached

I have some queries regarding mysql memcached such as :

**1** . What is the main difference between mysql cache and memcached ?mainly I want to ask what caching techniques are adopted in both of these?

**2** .What is the benefit of using memcached over mysql cache and What addiional functionality does memcached provide over mysql cache??
 **3** .Can I use memcached in my existing java application  without making any modifications to my existing JDBC code and if not then what necessary modifications do I need to make in my JDBC code.?? please explain with an example that how can i do this .

**4**. Is it good to use mysql memcached for frequently updating tables?

**5** . I want  to use memcached in my java application but I am  unable to find relevant examples so please provide me some examples showing that how can I use it ??

I have searched for the answers on web but was unable to find the relevant examples. So please provide the answers with a detailed explanation and some examples. 
Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Depending on engine used, MySQL will typically outperform `memcached`. [Reasoning and extended explanation found at the link](http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.de/2010/10/using-mysql-as-nosql-story-for.html)
2. Probably none, if anything you can very well end up wasting RAM for no significant benefit. There is no reason why connecting to `memcached` bears less strain than connecting to `MySQL` - both should be equally fast/slow, and many languages and frameworks implement connection pooling so that concurrent requests are served over established MySQL connections, therefore the performance loss due to connecting to MySQL is circumvented.
3. N/A
4. How would you use memcached for frequently updated tables? The data must be written to the disk, how will memcached help there? MySQL's cache is faster than memcached so I don't see how memcached helps you at all in this scenario.
5. N/A

I didn't refer to points 3 and 5 because there are googlable examples all over the net.

Long story short, you **don't need to use memcached with MySQL** if you use MySQL properly (proper dedicated server, with adequate InnoDB / TokuDB configuration, using prepared statements to alleviate SQL lexing on frequent queries).